# show_option_none not working in meta box

Tags: theme-development, admin, metabox

I have the following code going into a meta box:

```
function multi_author($post, $box)
{
$currentAuthors = esc_attr(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'multiAuthors', true));
if ($currentAuthors) {
    $authors = explode(',', $currentAuthors);
}
$y = 1;
for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {
    $output .= "Author #{$y}: " . wp_dropdown_users(array(
                'show_option_none' => '-- Select --',
                'echo' => 0,
                'name' => 'author' . $y,
                'selected' => $authors[$x],
                'who' => 'authors'
            )) . "<br/>";
    $y++;
}

echo $output;
}
```

If I place this code into a front end facing page, everything works as expected.  When this code is in a meta box, the 'show_option_none' tag is ignored and everything else works as planned.  Wordpress version 3.1.3 is being used. Any guesses as to why this is happening?

Comment: Code is working fine in a meta box so it must be something else, post your code.

Comment: There is the whole function

Answer (score 1):

I edited the codex to be more clear, but it already IS clear: This option forces the value to be "`-1`" so NONE can be selected. So '`show_option_none`' and '`selected`' don't play well together. I also saw that the "selected" string (/wp-includes/user.php - line 1010) is placed directly after the value attribute without a space. Could you check your sourcecode and verify this?

Comment: That line is the same in my source as well.

Comment: If this is the culprit, 'show_option_none' and 'selected' not working well together, then shouldn't this be true whether the code is public facing or only in the admin.  I'm only seeing issue in the admin.  I also don't see any edits to the codex in the wp_dropdown_users page.